# Is it possible to record a voice call using the agora sdk on a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, phone-call, agora.io

I am building an application that can record the phone calls that a user places through it. Is it possible to build this application using solely flutter and agora sdk? Is there anything else I would need? Any reference material to help with implementation is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently building a Flutter application myself that uses the Agora sdk. They make a good wrapper for Flutter framework you can learn more about [here.](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine)

I haven't looked much into the audio recording but some quick googling and I found this. Read more [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart/issues/161) .

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it manually by saving the file to the server as agora gives a .aac file on the path that we provide to the config of call recording. here's my code

````
 if (!_isJoined || _remoteUid == null) {
                                  Helper().showToast("You can't record now");
                                  return;
                                }
                                record = !record;
                                if (record) {
                                  String path =
                                      await Helper().getAudioFilePath();
                                  if (path.isEmpty) {
                                    Helper().showToast("Error in recording");
                                    record = false;
                                    setState(() {});
                                    return;
                                  }
                                  callController.callRecordingPath = path;
                                  AudioRecordingConfiguration config =
                                      AudioRecordingConfiguration(
                                    fileRecordingType: AudioFileRecordingType
                                        .audioFileRecordingMixed,
                                    filePath: path,
                                    quality: AudioRecordingQualityType
                                        .audioRecordingQualityMedium,
                                    sampleRate: AudioSampleRateType
                                        .audioSampleRate48000
                                        .value(),
                                  );
                                  Helper().showToast("Recording started");
                                  await agoraEngine.startAudioRecording(config);
                                } else {
                                  await agoraEngine.stopAudioRecording();
                                  callController
                                      .saveCallRecording(widget.callId);
                                  Helper().showToast("Recording stopped");
                                }
                                setState(() {});
    ```
````